# c pipes shell daemon with log capability not working

Tags: c, shell, logging, pipe, daemon

I have the following code:

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>



int main (void) {
int fd_s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP);
struct sockaddr_in info_s = {.sin_family=AF_INET,.sin_port=htons(1024),.sin_zero={0,0,0,0,0,0,0},.sin_addr.s_addr=0};
bind(fd_s,&info_s,sizeof(info_s));
listen(fd_s,1);
int info_s_len=sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
int fd_c;
struct sockaddr_in info_c;
while((fd_c=accept(fd_s, &info_c,&info_s_len))){
printf("client connected.\n");
if(!fork()){
int fd=open("log", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_APPEND|O_SYNC);
int p0[2],p1[2],p2[2];pipe2(p0, O_NONBLOCK);pipe2(p1, O_NONBLOCK);pipe2(p2, O_NONBLOCK);
dup2(p0[0], 0);
dup2(p1[1], 1);
dup2(p2[1], 2);
if(!fork()){
system("/bin/sh");
close(p0[0]);close(p0[1]);close(p1[0]);close(p1[1]);close(p2[0]);close(p2[1]);
close(fd_c);
close(fd);
printf("client disconnected.");
exit(0);
}else{
fd_set rd,wr;int on=1;//fcntl(fd_c, O_NONBLOCK, &on);
//char b[50];fwrite("ls;",3,1,fp_);fgets(b,50,fp_);printf(b);
FD_ZERO(&rd);FD_ZERO(&wr);
FD_SET(p1[0], &rd);FD_SET(p2[1],&rd);FD_SET(p0[1],&wr);FD_SET(fd_c, &rd);FD_SET(fd_c,&wr);
char *b=0; int bl,i;
while(select(p2[1]+1,&rd,&wr,0,0)){
char c;
if(FD_ISSET(fd_c,&rd)) {
b=realloc(b, 1*sizeof(char));
for(i=0,bl=1*sizeof(char);recv(fd_c,b+i,1,0)==1;i++,bl+=sizeof(char)){b=realloc(b, bl);}
write(p0[1],b,bl);
write(fd,b,bl);
free(b);
b=0;
}else if(FD_ISSET(p1[0],&rd)){
b=realloc(b, 1*sizeof(char));
for(i=0,bl=0;read(p0[0],b+i,1)>0;i++,bl+=sizeof(char)){b=realloc(b, bl);}
send(fd_c,b,bl,0);
write(fd,b,bl);
free(b);b=0;
}else if(FD_ISSET(p2[0],&rd)){
for(i=0,bl=0;read(p2[0],b+i,1)>0;i++,bl+=sizeof(char)){b=realloc(b, bl);}
send(fd_c,b,bl,0);
write(fd,b,bl);
free(b);b=0;
}
FD_ZERO(&rd);FD_ZERO(&wr);
FD_SET(p1[0], &rd);FD_SET(p2[1],&rd);FD_SET(p0[1],&wr);FD_SET(fd_c, &rd);FD_SET(fd_c,&wr);
}
}
}
}
return 0;
}
```

When I do a

```
telnet localhost 1024
```

my daemon spawns the `/bin/sh` and all sent commands are saved to the file `log`.
But, when I write (in example): `id;` I have no answer from my daemon into the client' side neither into the `log` file.

What am I missing?

P.D: the code needs some when client disconnected closing functions, which I will add when the pour pose is found.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`execve()` does not return, unless an error occurs.
therefore, none of the lines below this call are ever reached.

Use `system()` in order to continue after the child exits:

```
   The value returned is -1 on  error  (e.g.   fork(2)  failed),  and  the
   return  status  of the command otherwise.  This latter return status is
   in the format specified in wait(2).  Thus, the exit code of the command
   will  be  WEXITSTATUS(status).   In case /bin/sh could not be executed,
   the exit status will be that of a command that does exit(127).

   If the value of command is NULL, system() returns nonzero if the  shell
   is available, and zero if not.

   system() does not affect the wait status of any other children.
```

Comment: okay, thanks. I'm using system now and the child closes the file and returns the message. But the file is empty. I'm editing the code's adding the dup2 I've added for trying to log the buffer. Another thing I want to know if it is possible to undup2 the stdout (for example) once dup2ed because even closed the connection, the server is sending the message: "client disconnected" to the client' side.

Comment: sorry I deleted a comment because I thought I couldn't post another post because this is my second post and in the first I choosed: Answer your question and I couldn't post another for 7 hours. After I discovered I can post comments. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As follows is my solution.

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (void)
{
  int fd_s = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP);
  struct sockaddr_in info_s = {.sin_family = AF_INET,.sin_port =
      htons (1024),.sin_zero = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},.sin_addr.s_addr = 0
  };
  bind (fd_s, &info_s, sizeof (info_s));
  listen (fd_s, 1);
  int info_s_len = sizeof (struct sockaddr_in);
  int fd_c;
  struct sockaddr_in info_c;
  while ((fd_c = accept (fd_s, &info_c, &info_s_len)))
    {
      printf ("client connected.\n");
      if (!fork ())
    {
      int fd = open ("log", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND);
      int pty, tty;
      char *name;
      openpty (&pty, &tty, NULL, NULL, NULL);
      name = ttyname (tty);
      int p0[2], p1[2], p2[2];
      pipe (p0);
      pipe2 (p1, O_NONBLOCK);
      pipe2 (p2, O_NONBLOCK);
      dup2 (tty, 0);
      dup2 (tty, 1);
      dup2 (tty, 2);
      dup2 (p0[0], 0);
      dup2 (p1[1], 1);
      dup2 (p2[1], 2);
      if (!fork ())
        {
          system ("/bin/sh");
          close (p0[0]);
          close (p0[1]);
          close (p1[0]);
          close (p1[1]);
          close (p2[0]);
          close (p2[1]);
          close (fd_c);
          close (fd);
          // some log
          exit (0);
        }
      else
        {
          fd_set rd, wr;
          fcntl (fd_c, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
          FD_ZERO (&rd);
          FD_ZERO (&wr);
          FD_SET (p1[0], &rd);
          FD_SET (p2[0], &rd);
          FD_SET (fd_c, &rd);
          char *b = 0;
          int bl, i;
          while (select (p2[1] + 1, &rd, &wr, 0, 0))
        {
          char c;
          if (FD_ISSET (fd_c, &rd))
            {
              for (i = bl = b = 0; 1; i++)
            {
              char c;
              int ret = recv (fd_c, &c, sizeof (c), 0);
              if (ret == sizeof (c))
                {
                  bl += sizeof (char);
                  b = realloc (b, bl);
                  b[i] = c;
                }
              else if (ret == 0)
                {
                  close (fd_c);
                  free (b);
                  exit (0);
                }
              else if (ret == -1)
                {
                  write (p0[1], b, bl);
                  write (fd, b, bl);
                  free (b);
                  break;
                }
            }
            }
          else if (FD_ISSET (p1[0], &rd))
            {
              for (i = bl = b = 0; 1; i++)
            {
              char c;
              int ret = read (p1[0], &c, sizeof (c));
              if (ret == sizeof (c))
                {
                  bl += sizeof (c);
                  b = realloc (b, bl);
                  b[i] = c;
                }
              else if (ret == -1)
                {
                  send (fd_c, b, bl, 0);
                  write (fd, b, bl);
                  free (b);
                  break;
                }
              else
                {
                }
            }
            }
          else if (FD_ISSET (p2[0], &rd))
            {
              for (i = bl = b = 0; 1; i++)
            {
              char c;
              int ret = read (p2[0], &c, sizeof (c));
              if (ret == sizeof (c))
                {
                  bl += sizeof (c);
                  b = realloc (b, bl);
                  b[i] = c;
                }
              else if (ret == -1)
                {
                  send (fd_c, b, bl, 0);
                  write (fd, b, bl);
                  free (b);
                  break;
                }
            }
            }
          FD_ZERO (&rd);
          FD_ZERO (&wr);
          FD_SET (p1[0], &rd);
          FD_SET (p2[0], &rd);
          FD_SET (fd_c, &rd);
        }
        }
    }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks anyway...